# Querying Large Dataset on Join (15+ million rows)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to join two tables, `products` and `products_markets`. While `products` is under a million records, `product_markets` is closer to 20 million records. The data has been changed so there might be a typo or two in the schema create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_markets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country_code_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`product_id`,`country_code_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21052102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `popularity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `products_code_unique` (`code`),
  KEY `products_department_id_foreign` (`department_id`),
  KEY `products_manufacturer_id_foreign` (`manufacturer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_department_id_foreign`
       FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_manufacturer_id_foreign`
       FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=731563 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I am trying to return 50 records of the most popular products available in a specific country and I am running into times around ~50 seconds which seems higher than expected.

I've tried a few different queries with no success:

```
select  `products_markets`.`product_id`
    from  products_markets
    left join  
        ( SELECT  products.id, products.popularity
            from  products
        ) p  ON p.id = products_markets.product_id
    where products_markets.country_code_id = 121
    order by  `popularity` desc, `p`.`id` asc
    limit  50
```

and

```
select  `products`.*
    from  `products`
    where  products.id in (
        SELECT  product_id
            from  products_markets
            where  products_markets.country_code_id = 121
                          )
    group by  `products`.`name`, `products`.`manufacturer_id`
    order by  `popularity` desc, `products`.`id` asc
    limit  50
```

this query's explain is:

```
id  select_type  table              type possible_keys key           key_len refs             rows              extra
1   PRIMARY      products           ALL  PRIMARY       NULL          NULL    NULL             623848            Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY      products_markets   ref  unique_index  unique_index  4       main.products.id 14                Using where; Using index; FirstMatch(products)
```

One option I am entertaining is splitting up products_markets into individual tables for each country to lessen the query. I've tried adding more memory to the server without much success. Can anyone identify anything glaringly wrong with the database design/query?

What other options are available to make this query a fraction of its current ~50 seconds?

Comment: What does explain tell you? Are you using indexes?

Comment: I guess you should use indexes on both the table

Comment: @bhttoan I've added an explain to the last query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `id` in `products_markets` and add

```
PRIMARY KEY(country_code_id, product_id)
```

Then get rid of the `UNIQUE` key unless it is needed for some other query.

This will shrink the disk footprint of that large table significantly, thereby potentially speeding up all queries touching it.

And it will help with Hamaza's suggested reformulation.

Comment: Would removing timestamps significantly decrease query time or is it a negligible difference?

Comment: @chasenyc no it wont affect much unless you are selecting that field in the sql query but if timestamps are not required than better not to store the unwanted data in to the DB

Comment: This worked, removing the primary key and resetting it to the composite brought my query to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this what i meant by this query that you first select all products from the specified country's from products_market table than you select those products from products table by popularity and limit it to 50. Try not to do products.* and select only those fields whose data is needed.

```
select  products_markets.product_id, products_markets.county_code_id,
        products.*
    from  products_markets,products
    where  products_markets.country_code_id = 121
      and  products_markets.product_id=products.id
    group by  `products`.`name`, `products`.`manufacturer_id`
    order by  `products_markets.popularity` desc, `products`.`id` asc
    limit  50
```

Comment: This query was roughly ~40 seconds; however the second time I ran it, it seemed to have the results cached. While its possible this might be slightly quicker I definitely need to cut the query to much shorter.

Comment: @chasenyc you should try this query while setting index on country_code_id on products_market table

Comment: @chasenyc another option is you apply  limit your filter for products  on products_market but in this case you would not get most popular 50 products

Comment: @HamzaDairywala - More specifically, `INDEX(country_code_id, product_id)`.  If it does not hurt other queries, simply reverse the order of columns in the `UNIQUE` key.

Comment: I added the ALTER TABLE `products_markets` ADD INDEX `country_code_id` (`country_code_id`) and the query was ~46seconds

Comment: @chasenyc i guess you don't required group by product name as one product can not be more than once in one country so you can try removing groupby products.name and see if it reduces few more seconds

Comment: @HamzaDairywala unfortunately there can be multiple products with the same name and manufacturer and I only want to display one of each.

Comment: @chasenyc than you need to redesign the database and split the products table