# Trouble with Eloquent knowing actual primary (composite) key

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

There is a table in the database with the following initial migrations:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products_markets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('country_code_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
        });

    $sql = 'ALTER TABLE `products_markets` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`product_id`, `country_code_id`)';
    DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('products_markets');
}
```

And everything was working fine; however, once it was [realized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128824/querying-large-dataset-on-join-15-million-rows) that it did not make sense to have an auto-incrementing primary key `id` a new migration was made:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products_markets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::unprepared("ALTER TABLE products_markets ADD INDEX country_code_id (country_code_id)");
            DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE products_markets MODIFY id INT NOT NULL');
            DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE products_markets DROP PRIMARY KEY');
            DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE products_markets DROP COLUMN id');
            DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE products_markets ADD PRIMARY KEY (country_code_id, product_id)');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products_markets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::unprepared('DROP INDEX country_code_id ON products_markets');
            DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE products_markets DROP PRIMARY KEY');
            $table->increments('id');
        });
    }
```

While this code works on our server and **on some** machines locally, *other* machines seem to be throwing errors during tests:

> ProductTest::test_scopeMarket_only_returns_products_for_user_country
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update
>   `products_markets` set `country_code_id` = 121, `updated_at` =
>   2016-08-29 17:05:21 where `id` is null)

The test in question errors on the following line:

```
$products[0]->markets()->first()->update(['country_code_id' => 121]);
```

We have composer dumpautoload, re-migrating, clearing cache; however, nothing seems to help. Does this have to do with using `DB::unprepared` to `ALTER` the tables?

Comment: You should rewrite all queries where id used with a new primary key (`product_id`, `country_code_id`)

Comment: I guess I should elaborate that id is never used in any queries.

Comment: It seems it's used somewhere in test code.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before the failing conversion.

Comment: @RickJames Do you mean before the second migration? The migration does not fail and the table works I just can't update the model unless it is part of a query builder. See my answer below for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that [eloquent does not support composite primary keys](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355).

If you run :

`$products[0]->markets()->update(['country_code_id' => 121]);`

it will run; however, if you run:

`$products[0]->markets()->get()->update(['country_code_id' => 121]);`

it will fail because first() returns a model and the default model primaryKey is `id` and composite `primaryKey`s are not handled by Eloquent.

Comment: Alas, another case of 3rd party software getting in the way.